# CSS2 - Many subclasses, single parent

Tags: css, cross-browser

Usually I wrote this:

```
.parent .child1 { }
.parent .child2 { }
.parent .child3 { }
```

which is redundant for the `.parent` class.
Is there a way to declare `.parent` once? Such as:

```
.parent [
    .child1 { }
    .child2 { }
    .child3 { }
]
```

in CSS cross-browser?

Comment: No, in CSS, the optimal solution is the one you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) which allows nesting of selectors.

So you can write:

```
.parent {
    .child1 { }
    .child2 { }
    .child3 { }
}
```